# Can the way that I have used eval() be exploited?

Tags: python-3.6

I'm using a (very hacky) implementation of eval() to create dynamic sentences based on what the user has entered in. I'm well aware of the security problems that using eval() creates but I'm unable to find one myself. Are there any and, if so, what would be an alternate solution?

```
name = request.POST['name']
food = request.POST['food']
sen = "My name is {name}. " + "My favorite food is {food}. " #Would be created from a database table which lists all of the forms but, for the purposes of this example, this is what that would look like.
f = f'f"{sen}"'
ee = eval(f)
print(ee)
```

Comment: What you've posted here? No. But this is just nonsense code, because none of what you've posted has anything to do with `#from database` - it's a simple string concatenation of user input. If you have a real question, that contains actual code you're concerned about, post it.

Comment: My question is about whether there is any input that someone could enter into "name" which could cause problems when using eval(). The code itself is just a stripped down example designed to show what eval() is doing.